# How to make an iOS Side Navigation Drawer like the one in Gmail

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have checked out *several libraries, videos and online blogs* on how to make a side navigation drawer in iOS, but none of them have been able to provide a simple solution to create a side navigation drawer where you are **not limited to just a TableView**. I want to be able to add different UIViews to the side drawer. This is the kind of Side Drawer I am trying to create :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se0Xw.png)

Most of the libraries **cant allow custom views inside the side drawer**, but I want to create a small view [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCFvc.png) at the top of the drawer UITableView.

So far, I have tried these libraries but each of them lack an essential feature :

- https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController : Only supports a list of items(basically only a tableview) and not custom views like the one I want to add and like the one gmail has, which displays the profile picture along with the email id.
- https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu : Same Reason.
- https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu : Animation is too fancy.
- https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu : Only supports a TableView in the side drawer.

After having developed a few android applications, I was quite surprised that iOS didn't have an equivalent of the android `DrawerLayout`, and when I searched for libraries I could not find a single one that had the right classic design that is most used. I read somewhere that adding a side drawer was a bad design choice, but in my application, I have already used all of my screen space and need a way to give the user quick access to *20-25* list options along with a small view at the top. I figured adding a side drawer was the perfect way to do so, but unfortunately I haven't gotten very far trying to make it.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Create your own side menu

Comment: @Arundas How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) will let you stick any viewController with any layout you want into your menu.  Its really not that hard to make your own slide out either.  Your options are: 1. You make a container and every view in the app goes int he container along with the menu and the container animates the menu in an out.  Or 2. You just make a menu singleton and when it gets triggered it adds its view on top of the main window, which will cover the current view controller.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, I will check the library you sent me. But won't making one on my own based on the other options you wrote down require adding all the swipe events, transitions, drop shadows etc? Also, I am new to iOS application development and am not experienced in swipe gestures and transitions...

Comment: If you are new then use SlideMenuController.  Its while its easy to make your own menu, it does presuppose that you have a very good understanding of the view and viewcontroller hierarchy as well as core animation.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one also, [NavigationDrawer](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NavigationDrawer)